# Proving addition and multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, modular-forms

(1)Show that addition and multiplication mod n are associative operations.

(2)Show that there are both an additive and a multiplicative identity.

(3)Show that multiplication distributes over addition modulo n.

(4)Show that for every integer a there is an additive inverse -a:

---

I know, for both above, they mean that,

(1) (a+b)+c ≡ a+(b+c) (mod n)

(ab)c ≡ ba (mod n)

(2) a+0 ≡ a (mod n)
    a*1 ≡ a (mod n)

(3) a(b+c) ≡ ab+ac (mod n)

(4) a+(-a) ≡ ab+ac (mod n)

---

Professor said not to worry about the proofs for these, but I'd rather know it for future courses.��
This seems easy to grasp, for the lack of a better word, but I do not know how I would prove this since class just started.

Comment: Do anyone happen to know what these properties are called?

Comment: Your suggestion for property 4 seems to have an editing mistake; the right-hand side is the same as for property 3, but it should be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the hints for those problems:

1. Consider $a \bmod n$, $b \bmod n$ and $c \bmod n$.  Write those congruences in the form $z + nk$ where $k$ is any positive integers.  Add the first two congruences altogether and then, add that by $c \bmod n$.  Do the same for the right-hand side.  What do you know about $(a + b) + c \bmod n$ and $a + (b + c) \bmod n$.  Proving multiplicative associativity follows similarly as proving additive associativity.
2. Additive identity is $0$, whereas multiplicative identity is $1$.  To show there exists an identity, prove that in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, the set of integers modulo $n$, for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n$, $a + 0 = 0 + a = a \bmod n$ and $a \cdot 1 = 1 \cdot a = a \bmod n$.
3. Follow the similar steps for this problem as for the first problem.
4. If there exists an additive inverse, then for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n$, there exists $c \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $a + c = c + a = 0$.  Here $c = -a$.  I want you to prove this, starting with first similar steps for this problem also.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at this carefully and try to understand.  First real proof course for me.

Answer (score 1):

The main task is to show that these operations are well defined in the first place. The properties $(1)$–$(4)$ then follow by inspection.

Let an $n\geq1$ be given once and for all. Call two integers $x$ and $y$ *equivalent* if $x-y$ is an integer  multiple of $n$:
$$x\sim y\quad:\Longleftrightarrow\quad \exists j\in{\Bbb Z}:\quad x-y=j\>n\ .$$
Check that this is an equivalence relation. Denote the set of equivalence classes by ${\Bbb Z}_n$, and denote the equivalence class containing the number $x\in{\Bbb Z}$ by $[x]$. Define addition and multiplication of classes via representants, as follows:
$$[x]\oplus[y]:=[x+y],\qquad[x]\odot[y]:=[x\cdot y]\ .\tag{1}$$
One now has to check that the operations $\oplus$ and $\odot$ are well defined by $(1)$. This means that one has to verify that $[x]=[x']$ and $[y]=[y']$ together imply
$$[x+y]=[x'+y'],\quad [x\cdot y]=[x'\cdot y']\ .$$
Once this is accomplished the laws $(1)$–$(4)$ for ${\Bbb Z}_n$ immediately follow from the corresponding laws in ${\Bbb Z}$. It suffices to verify this for the first part of $(1)$:
$$\bigl([x]+[y]\bigr)+[z]=[x+y]+[z]=[x+y+z]=[x]+[y+z]=[x]+\bigl([y]+[z]\bigr)\ .$$